# can't select text in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, uiwebview

I'm using phongap with jquery mobile to develop ios app. Problem is user can't selet(copy/past) text in the browser. I used following code but it not working.

```
    -webkit-user-select: text;
```

Please help me.

Now i noticed reason for this issue is iscroll. when i remove the iscroll it working fine. But i need to use iscorll to this app. Please give me a solution.

Comment: you mean to say holding on text not brings copy button ??

Comment: both, I want to select text and copy if user want.

Comment: you have  jquery.mobile.vmouse.js file ????

Comment: see this link may solve your problem. [stackoveflow link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454177/holding-down-on-text-in-ios-does-not-bring-up-the-copy-button-on-jquerymobile)

Comment: I 'm not using jquery.mobile.dialog.js or 'vlink'. I'm only used jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js,jquery-1.7.1.min.js,iscroll.js and jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11725/discussion-between-hasintha-and-priyank-patel)